# Как сделать расстояние между ссылками и сделать текст по центру?

Tags: html, css

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    header{
     text-align:center;
    }
    .zag_header_1{
      text-transform:uppercase;
      margin-top:40px;
    }
    .main_text{
      text-align:center;
      margin-top:50px;
    }
    .main_text_2{
      margin-top:30px;
    }
    .main_link{
      text-align:center;
    }
    .zag_main_1{
      text-transform:uppercase;
      margin-top:50px;
    }
    
    
    footer{
      display:flex;
      align-items:flex-end;
      justify-content:center;
      height:70px;
      background-color:DimGray;
      text-align:center;
      
    }
    .text_footer{
      color:white;
      
    }
    
    .main_link_text a {
     display:inline-block;
     background-color:#C0C0C0;
     width:100%;
     height:50px; 
     border-radius:20px;
     text-decoration:none;
     color:#696969;
     text-transform:uppercase;
    }
    .main_link_text a:hover{
      background-color:#00CED1;
      color:white;
    }
   
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="icon_header"><img src="123.png" alt="иконка"></div>
    <div class="zag_header_1">
      <h1>Little web design agency</h1>
      <hr>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section class="main_text">
       <p class="main_text_1">We are a small web design agency based in Sheffield, UK. Over the las
       years weve worked with many companies and made a reputation
       for building websites that look great and are easy-to-use</p>
       <p class="main_text_2">We always take and shape your ideas and focus on simple
        ,elegant and usable solutions. We bring your project to life
        with clean and standarts-based code using the latest tech
        niques and technologies</p>
    </section>
    <section class="main_link">
      <div class="zag_main_1"><h2>Our services</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="main_link_text">
        <a class="main_link_text_tt" href="#">Design</a> <br>
        <a class="main_link_text_tt" href="#">Ui / Ux</a> <br>
        <a class="main_link_text_tt" href="#">Content</a>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <p class="text_footer">© 2020 Little web design agency</p>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для нижнего отступа использую `margin-bottom`, а для выравнивания по центру `line-height` и высоту кнопки.

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
}

.zag_header_1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.main_text {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.main_text_2 {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.main_link {
  text-align: center;
}

.zag_main_1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: DimGray;
  text-align: center;
}

.text_footer {
  color: white;
}

.main_link_text a {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #696969;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.main_link_text a:hover {
  background-color: #00CED1;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="main_text">
    <p class="main_text_1">We are a small web design agency based in Sheffield, UK. Over the las years weve worked with many companies and made a reputation for building websites that look great and are easy-to-use</p>
    <p class="main_text_2">We always take and shape your ideas and focus on simple, elegant and usable solutions. We bring your project to life with clean and standarts-based code using the latest tech niques and technologies</p>
  </section>
  <section class="main_link">
    <div class="zag_main_1">
      <h2>Our services</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="main_link_text">
      <a class="main_link_text_tt" href="#">Design</a><br>
      <a class="main_link_text_tt" href="#">Ui / Ux</a><br>
      <a class="main_link_text_tt" href="#">Content</a>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>

<footer>
  <p class="text_footer">© 2020 Little web design agency</p>
</footer>
```